# JSF 2.0, "preRenderView" event handler called twice

Tags: jsf-2

I have the following snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{workflowController.test}"/>
</f:metadata>

<h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    Hello, Place your content here
</h:body>

</html>
```

When I open the page, the WorkflowController.test() method is called twice (it's just a simple method which makes a log entry). Do you know why it's being called twice?

Thanks.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version exactly? I don't remember ever seeing this on Mojarra 2.0.x and 2.1.x.

Comment: I'm using [Glassfish JavaX dependencies](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-web-api/6.0/javaee-web-api-6.0.pom). I've also noticed that this happens only once, after restarting the domain. On all other successive requests, the event is triggered only once.

Comment: Late response, but I just walked into the same problem on my preRenderView. But in my situation, it happened every time instead of only after startup of the domain.

Comment: @Dario did you ever found a solution to that weird effect? Facing the same problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put the `<f:event/>` tag outside of the `<f:metadata>`, it worked for me (mojarra 2.1.0).